# oozie - sqoop $SQOOP_CONF_DIR has not been set in the environment

Tags: hadoop, oozie, sqoop

I am trying to run sqoop with oozie(horton works). this is the first time i trying to run the oozie workflow and i get the following error

```
Invoking Sqoop command line now
1811 [main] WARN org.apache.sqoop.tool.SqoopTool - $SQOOP_CONF_DIR has not been set in the environment. Cannot check for additional configuration. 
2015-12-21 16:58:45,913 WARN [main] tool.SqoopTool (SqoopTool.java:loadPluginsFromConfDir(177)) - $SQOOP_CONF_DIR has not been set in the environment. Cannot check for additional configuration. Intercepting System.exit(1) 
<<< Invocation of Main class completed 
<<< Failing Oozie Launcher, Main class [org.apache.oozie.action.hadoop.SqoopMain], exit code [1] Oozie Launcher failed, finishing Hadoop job gracefully Oozie Launcher, uploading action data to HDFS sequence file: hdfs://****/user/root/oozie-oozi/0000006-151121191305655-oozie-oozi-W/sqoop-node--sqoop/action-data.seq 
2015-12-21 16:58:45,971 INFO [main] zlib.ZlibFactory (ZlibFactory.java:<clinit>(49)) - Successfully loaded & initialized native-zlib library 
2015-12-21 16:58:45,973 INFO [main] compress.CodecPool (CodecPool.java:getCompressor(153)) - Got brand-new compressor [.deflate] Oozie Launcher ends 
2015-12-21 16:58:45,995 INFO [main] mapred.Task (Task.java:done(1038)) - Task:attempt_1448133067660_0066_m_000000_0 is done. And is in the process of committing 
2015-12-21 16:58:46,033 INFO [main] mapred.Task (Task.java:commit(1199)) - Task attempt_1448133067660_0066_m_000000_0 is allowed to commit now 
2015-12-21 16:58:46,044 INFO [main] output.FileOutputCommitter (FileOutputCommitter.java:commitTask(482)) - Saved output of task 'attempt_1448133067660_0066_m_000000_0' to hdfs://ip-10-39-154-114:8020/user/root/oozie-oozi/0000006-151121191305655-oozie-oozi-W/sqoop-node--sqoop/output/_temporary/1/task_1448133067660_0066_m_000000 
2015-12-21 16:58:46,081 INFO [main] mapred.Task (Task.java:sendDone(1158)) - Task 'attempt_1448133067660_0066_m_000000_0' done.
```

Answer (score 1):

No, it is not necessary to set `$SQOOP_CONF_DIR` but its good if you set it.
and you have some problem either related to your workflow.xml. There some cases when such problems occurs:

1. workflow.xml have some problem like inside `<command>...</command>` you have not passed arguments properly.
2. sqoop*.jar does not exist. etc.

but if you want to check what the real problem is then you can check it by yarn logs on command line by:

```
yarn logs -applicationId application_<app_id>
```

or 
you can also see your logs from web ui at :

```
<IP_WHERE_HADOOP_DEPOLYED>:8088/cluster
```

Comment: >>> Invoking Sqoop command line now >>>
 9175 [main] WARN  org.apache.sqoop.tool.SqoopTool  - 
$SQOOP_CONF_DIR has not been set in the 
environment. Cannot check for additional configuration.
 <<< Invocation of Main class completed <<<
Failing Oozie Launcher, Main class 
 [org.apache.oozie.action.hadoop.SqoopMain], exit 
 code [1]
Oozie Launcher failed, finishing Hadoop job gracefully
Oozie Launcher, uploading action data to HDFS sequence file: Oozie Launcher ends